# how let constructor parameter accept null value in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I know there is way to let parameter be a null like that:

```
function foo(bar: string | null) {
    console.info(bar);
}
```

but I am trying to reuse a code from an old project in a new project and I found something strange! see this code:

```
export class StateManagerService {
  //account manager
  accountState: AccountStateModel = new AccountStateModel(null, false);
   // ... many code after that
}
```

now just see what is in `AccountStateModel` class:

```
export class AccountStateModel extends BaseStatePartModel
{
    isLoggedIn:boolean;
    currentUser:UserInfo;
    constructor(currentUser:UserInfo,isLoggedIn:boolean)
    {
        super();
        this.currentUser=currentUser;
        this.isLoggedIn=isLoggedIn;
        this.stateKey=StateKeys.USER;
        this.keepInStorage=true;
    }
}
```

there is no error in old project, but in my recent project I get this error:
**Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UserInfo'.**
I expect to get this in my old project too, but there is no error there and it works fine! How this is possible?

Comment: Different tsconfig files and/or different TypeScript versions.

Comment: @HereticMonkey so do you know how we let tsconfig to ignore this error?

Comment: See especially `strictNullCheck`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks

Comment: @strictNullCheck  perfect, so this is possible :) thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The new project has either (or both) updated the Typescript version and the tsconfig file.

Newer Typescript is better at understanding types and the flow in your program, alas can understand that `null` is not assignable to `UserInfo`.

There are several solutions. The simplest, and the one most likely to bite you later on is to remove the functionality with parameters in tsconfig.
Another solution is so update the constructor to allow for null `constructor( currentUser:UserInfo|null, isLoggedIn: boolean)`. But this is ok only if `this.currentUser` is allowed to be null, domain wise.
A third option is to get rid of the null as nulls often are bad. But that is another story.

Comment: by this `constructor( currentUser:UserInfo|null, isLoggedIn: boolean)` you are just repeating what I point in question, the answer is what @HereticMonkey mention in comment.